# GDAL Delete geopackage layer

Tags: python, gdal, pygdal, geopackage

This seems like it ought to be straightforward:

```
from osgeo import gdal
gpkg = gdal.OpenEx('path_to_gpk',gdal.OF_VERBOSE_ERROR,allowed_drivers=['GPKG'])
error = gpkg.DeleteLayer(0)
```

After running this error is always a OGRERR_FAILURE. The geopackage has been created by QGIS so I would have thought should be standard.

Can't see any way to debug further into the GDAL calls apart from a GDB session, which I might try later.

Comment: Perhaps having a look at the GDAL autotests help https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_gpkg.py.

Answer (score 1):

Simple indeed....

Proper code below:

```
from osgeo import gdal
gpkg = gdal.OpenEx('path_to_gpk',gdal.OF_UPDATE,allowed_drivers=['GPKG'])
error = gpkg.DeleteLayer(0)
# above works with gdal.__version__ 3.4.2 without VACUUM call
# this code is also possible as an alternative
# doesn't seem to delete everything though, so possibly DeleteLayer() is better
# gpkg.ExecuteSQL('DROP TABLE [layer name]')
gpkg.ExecuteSQL('VACUUM')
```

Note that you will have to refresh any connections (e.g. in QGIS).

Comment: What remains after DROP TABLE? It certainly works when it is used as -sql parameter with ogrinfo.