# Properly closing GeoPackage after opening by OGR so as to delete it later

Tags: arcpy, ogr, geopackage, usgs, permissionerror

I am creating a program that downloads a GeoPackage from online, opens it, makes a copy of the first layer as a shapefile, and then (hopefully) deletes the GeoPackage. However, I'm not able to delete the GeoPackage; I get:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
> because it is being used by another process.

I have tried to set the GeoPackage data source to None as suggested in [Python - Correct way of closing ogr.DataSource() objects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380967/python-correct-way-of-closing-ogr-datasource-objects). And, it sounds like using a with statement is not an option as explained in [Use Python "with" statement for ogr.open(file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981614/use-python-with-statement-for-ogr-openfile). [GDAL Delete geopackage layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/339025/103382) led me to this [script](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_gpkg.py) from which I adapted some code:

```
gpkg_wesm = 'my/output/directory/WESM.gpkg'
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://rockyweb.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/Elevation/metadata/WESM.gpkg', filename = gpkg_wesm)
gpkg_ds = osgeo.ogr.Open(gpkg_wesm, update = 1)
assert gpkg_ds is not None
assert gpkg_ds.GetLayerCount() == 1, "unexpected number of layers; should be only one"
lyr0 = gpkg_ds.GetLayer(0)
assert lyr0.GetName() == "WESM", "unexpected layer name for layer; should be WESM"     
layer_wesm = os.path.join(gpkg_wesm, lyr0.GetDescription())     
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features = layer_wesm, out_path = 'my/output/directory', out_name = 'WESM.shp')
gpkg_ds = None
os.remove(gpkg_wesm)
```

Comment: Possibly the `arcpyy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` locking it??? Try `arcpy.Delete_management` instead of `os.remove`

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you use ogr for reading the gpkg why do you use arcpy for writing instead of ogr?

Comment: @user2856 Thanks for that suggestion. I did try arcpy.Delete_management and that did not work either. I should have mentioned that gives: arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:  ERROR 000601: Cannot delete

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for that suggestion and fair question. I am just more familiar with arcpy that GDAL and so I was trying to get the  gpkg to a shp since that's what I'm used to. My ultimate goal is to subset the gpkg layer based on another shp. I tried eliminating copying the gpkg to shp entirely and instead pointing to layer_wesm. The only issue is that arcpy is still locking it, I believe with my select by layer:     selection_layer = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(in_layer = layer_wesm, overlap_type = 'INTERSECT', select_features = shp_usfs_subset, selection_type = 'NEW_SELECTION')

Answer (score 2):

It occurred to me that if I was using data only to delete it later in the tool, than this was a good use case for storing the data in the ArcGIS Pro Scratch Folder in the first place (which should clear itself). I assign working directory to the scratchFolder and then use an absolute path for the output to be written to disk (in real life I am subsetting based on select by location with another shapefile, but copying the feature class serves as an example here). Removing the path from the filename string (gpkg_wesm variable) results in it being saved to the scratchFolder by default. Modified code below:

```
import urllib, osgeo.ogr, os, arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.env.scratchFolder

gpkg_wesm = 'WESM.gpkg'
    
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://rockyweb.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/Elevation/metadata/WESM.gpkg', filename = gpkg_wesm)

gpkg_ds = osgeo.ogr.Open(gpkg_wesm, update = 1)
# Open GeoPackage data source

assert gpkg_ds is not None

assert gpkg_ds.GetLayerCount() == 1, "unexpected number of layers; should be only one"

lyr0 = gpkg_ds.GetLayer(0)

assert lyr0.GetName() == "WESM", "unexpected layer name for layer; should be WESM"     

#Assign variable to layer name in GeoPackgae
layer_wesm = os.path.join(gpkg_wesm, lyr0.GetDescription())     
    
# Use layer name to point to SQLite database feature class and export as shapefile
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features = layer_wesm, out_path = 'my/output/directory', out_name = 'WESM.shp')
```